# Open and close windows

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, pyqt5, window

I'm trying to create a simple app which consist of two windows. The first one is a **Login Page** and the second is a **Registration page**. The dynamics are as follows:

1. The first window is the Login window with two buttons; Login Button and Register Button.
2. If the login button is clicked, it starts a session if the credentials are correct.
3. Clicking the second button should close this window and open a new registration window.
4. The registration window has two buttons as well, the first simply confirm the registration, the second is to cancel the registration.
5. This cancel button is supposed to close the current window and open the Login window.

---

Steps 1 through 4 work perfectly, but in **step 5** it keeps does not close the current window and simply opens a new Login windows.

Please write a basic code as an example of how to close the window using **PyQT5**. I don't want you to write all code but just a generic one. I just want to have an idea how it works and use it in my own code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing and hiding multiple windows in PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060506/showing-and-hiding-multiple-windows-in-pyqt5)

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank you for your patience and help. Unfortunately, it doesn't help me. I read the codes and they're similar mine. One code opens the Login window, this one opens a second window and when a button in this second one is clicked it opens the login window and the second one doesn't close.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem will be to implement a separate controller class. This class will control all the windows you want to show or hide.

This link will take you to a similar question which has the [code you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49069756).

GitHub [link to code](https://gist.github.com/MalloyDelacroix/2c509d6bcad35c7e35b1851dfc32d161)

Source: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49069756)

Comment: The code is very interesting but it's not what I really need. This controller class creates a third window just to close the program and that's not what I'd like to do.